# Using plotly.graph_objects, is there way to trim or wrap the label text inside of each box when the box is too small?

Tags: plotly, treemap, plotly.graph-objects

If you look here: https://plotly.com/python/treemaps/#nested-layers-in-treemap, looking at the image:
[image]

Note the tiny text in the second small block.  You can hardly see it because the text is "Blackcurrant-like", and it's too big to fit.

None of the current options proposed in the documentation are sufficient.

#### Proposed solution 1: Force the font size to be bigger, hide if it won't fit.

By adding this line:

```
    fig.update_layout(uniformtext=dict(minsize=11, mode='hide'))
```

It hides labels that don't fit:

[image]

And that's not very good.  I want to be able to see the text.

#### Proposed solution 2: Force the font size to be bigger, force show if it won't fit.

```
    fig.update_layout(uniformtext=dict(minsize=11, mode='show'))
```

[image]

That solves the problem in the text hiding, but now it draws outside of the box, which is not good.

What I would like is for the text to wrap.  If that's not possible, then I would like it to trim (possibly with ellipses).  I can't figure out a way to do either with this library.
So my first question is, is it possible?

#### Proposed solution 3: Trim text ahead of time.

If I knew ahead of time that the text won't fit, I could trim it.   But how do I know that, and how can I tell by how much I can trim it?
I suppose, since the the size of the box is indirectly related to the value we pass it, we can make a guess as to which boxes are going to be too small for the text we pass in.  But how?  I don't even know the shame of the box.  Below it's a tall rectangle.  There's no way for me to guess that.
If there was an event I can hook on where the UI calls me back before rending the text, giving me the dimensions of the square, allowing me to change the text, I might have a chance.

Any suggestions?

Seems silly to have all that space in the box that I can't populate.  I'm assuming there's some technical reason why the text can't wrap since that would have been the most obvious solution.

Comment: When the box is too small, do you want single words to also wrap even if wraps from the middle of the word?

Comment: I'll take anything at this point, but word-breaks would be ideal.

Comment: I have no idea why the text can't wrap and I agree that this feature would be useful  across all Plotly graph_objects — and not just for treemaps. The boxes resize as the browser window changes which makes things trickier, but I'll see what I can figure out

Comment: Hi there, I ran into the same problem and I think one solution could be to use the library textwrap, in order to trim the text with a given width. See this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62151608/how-to-wrap-text-in-plotly-pys-sunburst-diagram

Comment: @Vincent thank you for your reply, but this doesn't work for me because i would have to know what the width is ahead of time.   The whole point of a TreeMap is that the width is dynamic -- it's calculated dynamically using the tree-map algorithm which you'd have to duplicate exactly to determine the width ahead of time.   At that point, might as well fork the plotly library and make the change there.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your text manually by using `<br>` among the text, take this example [here](https://plotly.com/python/treemaps/):

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.treemap(df, path=[px.Constant("all"), 'day', 'time', 'sex'], values='total_bill')
fig.update_traces(root_color="lightgrey")
fig.update_layout(margin = dict(t=50, l=25, r=25, b=25))
fig.show()
```

[image]

I will add a long label with manual wrapping.

```
fig.data[0]['labels'][0:6] = "This is too long label <br> but it is wrapped <br> into three lines"
fig.data[0]['textfont']['size'] = 20
fig.show()
```

[image]